How to show that $B(a,r) \cap A = B(a,\operatorname{diam } A) \cap A$ for an open and bounded set $A$, where $a \in A$ and $r > \text{diam A}$?
The following problem came up amid one of my classes.
Problem. Suppose that $A$ is an open and bounded set with diameter denoted by $\operatorname{diam } A$. Show that for every element $a \in A$ and radius $r > 0$ such that $r > \operatorname{diam } A$ there holds
$$ B(a,r) \cap A = B(a,\operatorname{diam } A) \cap A. $$
My attempt. I was able to deal with the inclusion $(\supset)$ in the following way:
Consider an arbitrary element $y \in B(a,\operatorname{diam } A) \cap A$. Then, in order to show the inclusion mentioned above it is sufficient to show that $y \in B(a,r)$. This follows directly by recalling that $r > \operatorname{diam } A$, since then
$$ |y-a| < \operatorname{diam } A < r, $$
which implies that $y \in B(a,r)$.
On the other hand, I am having some trouble with the reverse inclusion. Consider an arbitrary element $B(a,r) \cap A$. In order to show the converse inclusion all that we need to prove is that $y \in B(a,\operatorname{diam } A)$. Now, from the definition of diameter, it is clear that
$$ |y - a| \leqslant \sup_{a,y \in A} |y - a| =: \operatorname{diam } A. $$
This guarantees that $y \in \overline{B(a,\operatorname{diam } A)}$ but I am not sure how to deduce the strict inequality.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Hint: if $|a-y|$ is the diameter of $A$, can you find a ball around $y$ inside $A$?

@WhileIAm Thanks for your comment. You seem to be suggesting me to assume that $|a- y| = \operatorname{diam } A$ and to try and reach a contradiction. I don't understand exactly what you mean by "can you find a ball around $y$ inside $A$." Can you give a further hint about this ? Is this related with $A$ being open ?

The result as quoted is false for general (pseudo)metric spaces. Particularly the inclusion $\subseteq$ might not be true due to the step you had trouble with. The inequality is not necessarily strict.
A counterexample would be any (pseudo)metric space which has an open set whose diameter (supremum) is larger than zero and is achieved. Even two points with the discrete metric, or a circle with the standard metric would do the trick.
So, in general, either the RHS needs to have the closed ball as you point out, or additional assumptions are needed. Namely the diameter should be zero or it should not be achievable (maximum should not exist).
I noticed right before posting that you have the tag real analysis. If this is meant in the restrictive sense, I'll say the following. For $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard metric, these "additional assumptions" from above hold, so the result in this concrete case is true.

Namely show that for any open set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard metric,

If $\operatorname{diam}{A} > 0$, then there cannot exist $x, y \in A$ such that $\varrho(x,y) = \operatorname{diam}{A}$.

If $\operatorname{diam}{A} = 0$, then $A$ would be a singleton but singletons are not open in this metric space. (All singletons are always closed in metric spaces, in T1-spaces more generally. But some singletons could additionally be open in other metric spaces, if they are isolated points. Though not in $
\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard metric.)



If $\operatorname{diam}{A} = -\infty$, i.e. $A = \varnothing$, the equality in OP holds vacuously.

Thanks for your answer. I should've mentioned in the post that $A$ is indeed a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (sorry for this inconvenience). With this in mind, I believe that my question can be resumed to the following: " Given an open set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ with $\operatorname{diam } A > 0$, how can one prove that there cannot exist $x,y \in A$ such that $|x-y| = \operatorname{diam } A$". I've made a sketch about this proof, perhaps you can help me formalising it ? I've used a reasoning by contradiction. See next comment.

Suppose that there exist $x,y \in A$ satisfying $|x-y| = \operatorname{diam } A$. Since $A$ is open and $y \in A$, there exists a ball $B(y,\epsilon) \subset A$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is a sufficiently small element. Now, intuitively I can see that it is possible to pick a certain element in this ball whose distance to $x$ is greater than $|x-y|$, which contradicts the fact that $|x-y| = \operatorname{diam } A$, but I am not sure how to formally define such element.

@TemirbekAlikhadzhiyev The problem is indeed that such a ball $\mathrm{B}(y, \epsilon) \subseteq A$, $\epsilon > 0$, should exist but does not. Construct the straight line $\ell_{xy}$ connecting $x$ and $y$. Now no points on this line beyond $y$ (in the opposite direction from $x$) can belong to $A$, for then the diameter would be strictly bigger than itself. But at least some points on the line $l_{xy}$ beyond $y$ should belong to $A$ because they are in $\mathrm{B}(y, \epsilon)$.
